# how to find index of the first capital letter in mysql, cyrillic characters

Tags: mysql

I have a table with geographical names of places. Sometimes they have additional letters in front. for example if the city name is Astana then it is `s.Astana`. I need to get only the name of the place Astana. I want to use `substr`, but I can't find the index of first capital letter.Owh ya cyrillic characters are used that is also a problem.  I want to give some examples:

1. Акмолинская область   -> Акмолинская
2. Кокшетау Г.А.         -> Кокшетау
3. г.Кокшетау            -> Кокшетау
4. Красноярский с.о.     -> Красноярский
5. с.Красный Яр          -> Красный Яр

What i have tried: 
created a field short_nameru and updated it this way

```
UPDATE center_kato ck SET ck.short_nameru = case when 
  LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ck.nameru , ' ', -1)) > LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ck.nameru , ' ',1))
  then SUBSTRING_INDEX(ck.nameru , ' ', -1)
  else SUBSTRING_INDEX(ck.nameru , ' ',1) 
  END
```

and after that i updated it again

```
UPDATE center_kato ck SET ck.short_nameru = case 
  when LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ck.short_nameru , '.', -1)) > LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ck.short_nameru , '.',1))
  then SUBSTRING_INDEX(ck.short_nameru , '.', -1)
  WHEN LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ck.short_nameru , '.', -1)) < LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ck.short_nameru , '.',1)) 
  then SUBSTRING_INDEX(ck.short_nameru , '.',1)
  ELSE ck.short_nameru 
  END
```

but i lost some needed values. `"зимовка Туяк"` became `"зимовка"` but i needed `"Туяк"`

Comment: Suggest you post your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot think of a way to find a pattern in a string.  Here is a brute force approach:

```
select (case when ascii(substr(CityName, 1, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
             then CityName
             when ascii(substr(CityName, 2, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
             then substr(CityName, 2)
             when ascii(substr(CityName, 3, 1)) between ascii('A' and ascii('Z')
             then substr(CityName, 3)
             when ascii(substr(CityName, 4, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
             then substr(CityName, 4)
             when ascii(substr(CityName, 5, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
             then substr(CityName, 5)
             when ascii(substr(CityName, 6, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
             then substr(CityName, 6)
             when ascii(substr(CityName, 7, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
             then substr(CityName, 7)
             when ascii(substr(CityName, 8, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
             then substr(CityName, 8)
             when ascii(substr(CityName, 9, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
             then substr(CityName, 9)
             when ascii(substr(CityName, 10, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
             then substr(CityName, 10)
             else CityName
        end)
```

If you know the preceding character is always a `'.'`, then there are other approaches.

EDIT:

The following seems to be working in Cyrillic:

```
select    
    (case when substr(nameru, 1, 1) between BINARY 'А' AND BINARY 'Я' then nameru
    when substr(nameru, 2, 1) between BINARY 'А' AND BINARY 'Я' then substr(nameru, 2)
    when substr(nameru, 3, 1) between BINARY 'А' AND BINARY 'Я' then substr(nameru, 3)
    when substr(nameru, 4, 1) between BINARY 'А' AND BINARY 'Я' then substr(nameru, 4)
    when substr(nameru, 5, 1) between BINARY 'А' AND BINARY 'Я' then substr(nameru, 5)
    when substr(nameru, 6, 1) between BINARY 'А' AND BINARY 'Я' then substr(nameru, 6)
    when substr(nameru, 7, 1) between BINARY 'А' AND BINARY 'Я' then substr(nameru, 7)
    when substr(nameru, 8, 1) between BINARY 'А' AND BINARY 'Я' then substr(nameru, 8)
    when substr(nameru, 9, 1) between BINARY 'А' AND BINARY 'Я' then substr(nameru, 9)
    when substr(nameru, 10, 1) between BINARY 'А' AND BINARY 'Я' then substr(nameru, 10)
         else nameru
        end)
FROM mytable;
```

(For some reason, editors rejected the edit by yernanun, so I'm including it.)

Comment: sometimes there is no '.'

Comment: I just give u examples. Owh ya cyrillic characters are used that is also a problem. 
Акмолинская область   -> Акмолинская,
Кокшетау Г.А.         -> Кокшетау,
г.Кокшетау            -> Кокшетау,
Красноярский с.о.     -> Красноярский,
с.Красный Яр          -> Красный Яр,

Comment: @yernarun . . . This approach should adapt quite readily to Cyrillic.  I'm wondering why you unaccepted it.

Comment: Beacuse this "SELECT CASE when 'A' BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z' THEN 'betwwen' ELSE 'not between' END" and this "SELECT CASE when 'A' BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z' THEN 'betwwen' ELSE 'not between' END" is the same

Comment: @yernarun . . . You're right.  The default collation is case-insensitive.  I fixed the answer to use the `ascii()` function, to avoid fiddling around with collations.

Comment: i did it this way"case when substr(nameru, 1, 1) between BINARY 'А' AND BINARY 'Я' then nameru"

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(city, '.', -1) as Place
FROM
  yourtable
```

The negative value (-1) will perform a reverse search from the tail of the string and return the tail (right-most) portion.

**Edit**

Given your sample data above, i think that this query should return what you need:

```
SELECT
  yourtable.id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(city, first_upper), ' ', 1) city_name
FROM
  yourtable INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      id,
      MIN(CASE WHEN (MID(yourtable.city, numbers.n, 1) != '\.') AND
                    (UPPER(MID(yourtable.city, numbers.n, 1))=BINARY
                    MID(yourtable.city, numbers.n, 1))
               THEN numbers.n END) first_upper
    FROM
      numbers, yourtable
    GROUP BY
      id) f
  ON yourtable.id = f.id;
```

Please have a look at [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10fe4/1).

You need a numbers table that contains numbers from 1 to the maximum lenght of your string to simulate a for loop. In my subquery I'm calculating, for each city, the minimum position in the string that doesn't contain a `.`, and where the character contained in that position is equal to that character in uppercase (we need a binary comparison here). If the condition is true, it means that the character is in uppercase already (or it means that it is a special character, like `; ! ?` but we need to exclude them).

I'm then extracting the substring from the calculated position, until the first space character.

Comment: sometimes there is no '.'

Comment: @yernarun a city name could be sAstana, and you still need to extract Astana?

Comment: I just give u examples. Owh ya cyrillic characters are used that is also a problem. Акмолинская область -> Акмолинская, Кокшетау Г.А. -> Кокшетау, г.Кокшетау -> Кокшетау, Красноярский с.о. -> Красноярский, с.Красный Яр -> Красный Яр

Comment: @yernarun I've updated my answer, I'm not familiar with cyrillic characters, but i think that it should work

Answer (score 1):

**[Here is SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e0bb/4)**

**Below is the Approach:**

```
SELECT substring_index(col1, 
                       '.', 
                       -1) as Place
FROM temp
WHERE col1 LIKE '%\.%'
```